# Stream filter large number of lines that are specified by line number from stdin

Tags: bash, unix, awk, stream, large-files

I have a huge `xz` compressed text file `huge.txt.xz` with millions of lines that is too large to keep around uncompressed (60GB).

I would like to **quickly** filter/select a large number of lines (~1000s) from that huge text file into a file `filtered.txt`. The line numbers to select could for example be specified in a separate text file `select.txt` with a format as follows:

```
10
14
...
1499
15858
```

Overall, I envisage a shell command as follows where "TO BE DETERMINED" is the command I'm looking for:

```sh
xz -dcq huge.txt.xz | "TO BE DETERMINED" select.txt >filtered.txt
```

I've managed to find an `awk` program from a closely related question that almost does the job - the only problem being that it takes a *file name* instead of reading from *stdin*. Unfortunately, I don't really understand the `awk` script and don't know enough `awk` to alter it in such a way to work in this case.

This is what works right now with the disadvantage of having a 60GB file lie around rather than streaming:

```sh
xz -dcq huge.txt.xz >huge.txt
awk '!firstfile_proceed { nums[$1]; next } 
         (FNR in nums)' select.txt firstfile_proceed=1 >filtered.txt
```

Inspiration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612680/remove-lines-with-specific-line-number-specified-in-a-file

Comment: Are the numbers in `select.txt` always sorted such that the largest value comes last?

Comment: You might consider switching to zstd for compression instead of xz. It's a lot faster, especially at decompression.

Comment: @ed `select.txt` can be sorted if that helps, it's not the rate limiting step here if there are just thousands to millions lines to be chosen, since sorting is `n*log n`

Comment: @shawn The compression format is given. I think xz is chosen for a good reason as the underlying data is biological sequence data with roughly 30k basepairs (sars-cov-2) and xz does pretty well there compressing 60 GB to just 500 MB.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer I understand  that, I asked because it's just a minor difference between needing `max=$1` if that file is sorted or `max=($1>max ? $1 : max)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049677/1745001) otherwise to determine the largest value from that file so we can stop processing after reaching it. Sounds like your answer is that it's not sorted which is fine, it's easily handled either way.

Comment: Oh it'd just be an feature if it doesn't have to be sorted. Thanks for considering this!

Comment: zstd rivals xz compression ratios, fwiw.

Comment: @shawn thanks for the suggestion, wasn't aware of it and will try out for sequence data (very particular dictionary)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keeping with OP's current idea:

```
xz -dcq huge.txt.xz | awk '!firstfile_proceed { nums[$1]; next } (FNR in nums)' select.txt firstfile_proceed=1 -
```

Where the `-` (at the end of the line) tells `awk` to read from stdin (in this case the output from `xz` that's being piped to the `awk` call).

Another way to do this (replaces all of the above code):

```
awk '
FNR==NR { nums[$1]; next }             # process first file
FNR in nums                            # process subsequent file(s)
' select.txt <(xz -dcq huge.txt.xz)
```

Comments removed and cut down to a 'one-liner':

```
awk 'FNR==NR {nums[$1];next} FNR in nums' select.txt <(xz -dcq huge.txt.xz)
```

---

Adding some logic to implement Ed Morton's comment (exit processing once FNR > largest value from `select.txt`):

```
awk '
# process first file

FNR==NR      { nums[$1]
               maxFNR= ($1>maxFNR ? $1 : maxFNR)
               next
             }

# process subsequent file(s):

FNR > maxFNR { exit }
FNR in nums
' select.txt <(xz -dcq huge.txt.xz)
```

**NOTES:**

- keeping in mind we're talking about scanning millions of lines of input ...
- `FNR > maxFNR` will obviously add some cpu/processing time to the overall operation (though less time than `FNR in nums`)
- if the operation routinely needs to pull rows from, say, the last 25% of the file then `FNR > maxFNR` is likely providing little benefit (and probably slowing down the operation)
- if the operation routinely finds all desired rows in, say, the first 50% of the file then `FNR> maxFNR` is probably worth the cpu/processing time to keep from scanning the entire input stream (then again, the `xz` operation, on the entire file, is likely the biggest time consumer)
- net result: the additional `NFR > maxFNR` test may speed-up/slow-down the overall process depending on how much of the input stream needs to be processed in a typical run; OP would need to run some tests to see if there's a (noticeable) difference in overall runtime

Answer (score 1):

To clarify my previous comment. I'll show a simple reproducible sample:

`linelist` content:

```
10
15858
14
1499
```

To simulate a long input, I'll use `seq -w 100000000`.

Comparing sed solution with my suggestion, we have:

```
#!/bin/bash

time (
    sed 's/$/p/' linelist > selector
    seq -w 100000000 | sed -nf selector
)
time (
    sort -n linelist | sed '$!{s/$/p/};$s/$/{p;q}/' > my_selector
    seq -w 100000000 | sed -nf my_selector
)
```

output:

```
000000010
000000014
000001499
000015858

real    1m23.375s
user    1m38.004s
sys 0m1.337s
000000010
000000014
000001499
000015858

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.014s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comparing my solution with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

time (
    awk '
# process first file

FNR==NR      { nums[$1]
               maxFNR= ($1>maxFNR ? $1 : maxFNR)
               next
             }

# process subsequent file(s):

FNR > maxFNR { exit }
FNR in nums
' linelist <(seq -w 100000000)
)

time (
    sort -n linelist | sed '$!{s/$/p/};$s/$/{p;q}/' > my_selector
    sed -nf my_selector <(seq -w 100000000)
)
```

output:

```
000000010
000000014
000001499
000015858

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.001s
000000010
000000014
000001499
000015858

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.001s
```

In my conclusion, `seq` using `q` is comparable with `awk` solution. For readability and maintainability I prefer `awk` solution.

Anyway, this test is simplistic and only useful for small comparisons. I don't know, for example, what the result would be if I test this against the real compressed file, with heavy disc I/O.

---

**EDIT by Ed Morton:**

Any speed test that results in all output values that are less than a second is a bad test because:

1. In general no-one cares if X runs in 0.1 or 0.2 secs, they're both fast enough unless being called in a large loop, and
2. Things like cache-ing can impact the results, and
3. Often a script that runs faster for a small input set where execution speed doesn't matter will run slower for a large input set where execution speed DOES matter (e.g. if the script that's slower for the small input spends time setting up data structures that will allow it to run faster for the larger)

The problem with the above example is it's only trying to print 4 lines rather than the 1000s of lines that the OP said they'd have to select so it doesn't exercise the difference between the sed and the awk solution that causes the sed solution to be much slower than the awk one which is that the sed solution has to test every target line number for every line of input while the awk solution just does a single hash lookup of the current line. It's an order(N) vs order(1) algorithm on each line of the input file.

Here's a better example showing printing every 100th line from a 1000000 line file (i.e. will select 1000 lines) rather than just 4 lines from any size file:

```
$ cat tst_awk.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1000000
m=100
awk -v n="$n" -v m="$m" 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=n; i+=m) print i}' > linelist

seq "$n" |
    awk '
        FNR==NR {
            nums[$1]
            maxFNR = $1
            next
        }
        FNR in nums {
            print
            if ( FNR == maxFNR ) {
                exit
            }
        }
    ' linelist -
```

```
$ cat tst_sed.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1000000
m=100
awk -v n="$n" -v m="$m" 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=n; i+=m) print i}' > linelist

sed '$!{s/$/p/};$s/$/{p;q}/' linelist > my_selector
seq "$n" |
    sed -nf my_selector
```

```
$ time ./tst_awk.sh > ou.awk

real    0m0.376s
user    0m0.311s
sys     0m0.061s
```

```
$ time ./tst_sed.sh > ou.sed

real    0m33.757s
user    0m33.576s
sys     0m0.045s
```

As you can see the awk solution ran 2 orders of magnitude faster than the sed one, and they produced the same output:

```
$ diff ou.awk ou.sed
$
```

If I make the input file bigger and select 10,000 lines from it by setting:

```
n=10000000
m=1000
```

in each script, which is probably getting more realistic for the OPs usage, the difference becomes really impressive:

```
$ time ./tst_awk.sh > ou.awk

real    0m2.474s
user    0m2.843s
sys     0m0.122s
```

```
$ time ./tst_sed.sh > ou.sed

real    5m31.539s
user    5m31.669s
sys     0m0.183s
```

i.e. awk runs in 2.5 seconds while sed takes 5.5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file of line numbers, add `p` to the end of each and run it as a `sed` script.

If `linelist` contains

```
10
14
1499
15858
```

then `sed 's/$/p/' linelist > selector` creates

```
10p
14p
1499p
15858p
```

then

```
$: for n in {1..1500}; do echo $n; done | sed -nf selector
10
14
1499
```

I didn't send enough lines through to match 15858 so that one didn't print.

This works the same with a decompression from a file.

```
$: tar xOzf x.tgz | sed -nf selector
10
14
1499
```

Comment: That would be orders of magnitude slower than just running an awk script. When I ran the awk script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049677/1745001 on an input file thats 1 million lines long against a list of lines to print that's 1 in every 100 it completed in 0.6 of a second. When I did the same with the sed approach I killed it after it had been running for a minute.

Comment: That's true... Every check on every line. Good point.

Comment: Just rewrite the command `sed 's/$/p/' linelist > selector` to `sed '$!{s/$/p/};${s/$/{p;q}/}'`, using the command `q`, sed will stop processing after last line number like awk examples.

Comment: @RonaldoFerreiradeLima that's still going to be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script and it'd rely on the contents of `linelist` being sorted which the OP said it isn't (but of course it would be easy to add a call to `sort` before running sed on it).

Comment: @Ed Morton, I tried to create an example of using the `q` command from `sed` to better explain my point of view.

Comment: @RonaldoFerreiradeLima hope you don''t mind but I edited your answer to show a better way to test the difference between the 2 solutions.

Comment: In fact, it was a very good example. Thanks @Ed Morton.